# Display list/library title in breadcrumb

Tags: navigation, publishing-page, breadcrumb

I have standard publishing site with subsite and list on that subsite. When user enters list, in breadcrumb he sees something like this: `[root site title] > [subsite title]` but I'd like to show: `[root site title] > [subsite title] > [list title]`

How I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You already have a breadcrumb beside the Site Actions button on the top in the ribbon, however you can have a breadcrumb navigation where the Site Name lies as discussed in below article:
[Improving the SharePoint breadcrumb navigation](http://www.nothingbutbranding.com/blog/2012/july/improving-the-sharepoint-breadcrumb-navigation)

Also, seems to be a duplicate of the question on stackoverflow:
[Implementing a breadcrumb into your SharePoint 2010 website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449631/implementing-a-breadcrumb-into-your-sharepoint-2010-website)

Extract from answer:

> Technet says [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee695757.aspx#Section2c) Breadcrumb navigation displays a dynamically
>   generated set of links at the top of Web pages, to show users their
>   current position in the site hierarchy. By using SharePoint Designer
>   2010 or Visual Studio 2010, you can configure the breadcrumb
>   navigation control. For example, you can specify a custom navigation
>   provider, and you can remove breadcrumb navigation from a page layout.
>
> This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms558975.aspx) discusses creating a custom navigation provider.
>
> This is a control that you can add to sharepoint found on CodePlex
>   ([mavention](http://mavention.codeplex.com/releases/view/43361))